# Using Google Script to Input Google Drive Files' URLs into Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api, postman

Sorry in advance, but I think I should start by saying I'm not a dev nor do I have any dev knowledge. And I'm really hoping you could help me with this.

Scenario:

- I have a folder in My Drive with several PDFs
- I have a Google sheet with 2 columns, first column is "Name" and second column is "Document". The first column is filled with several names and the second column is entirely empty

What i want to do:

- Import the URLs/links of the PDFs into the "Document" columns corresponding to the names. So John's PDF document should be in the same row with John's name

Answer (score 0):

Go to [script.google.com](http://script.google.com) paste this code and run it:

```js
function main () {
  files = DriveApp.getFilesByType("application/pdf");
  var names = [];
  var links = [];

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    names.push([file.getName()]);
    links.push([file.getUrl()]);
}
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("My favourite pdf");
  Logger.log(newSpreadsheet.getUrl());
  var newSheet = newSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  newSheet.getRange("A1:A"+names.length).setValues(names);
  newSheet.getRange("B1:B"+names.length).setValues(links);
}
```

Then, on the top menu, press View and check logs. You'll find the url of your document, you'll also find it on [Google Spreadsheets](http://spreadsheets.google.com)

Here you have an introduction on how to start with Apps Script:
[Tutorials: Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials)

Hope it works for you,
Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just had a chance to get online. And thank you very much for your help, i will try it out first.

Comment: Hi Yuri, is the script above for pulling all PDFs in My Drive (or even Shared Drives and Shared With Me)? Is there a way to target only one folder in My Drive?

Comment: Always got this error "The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 9870." [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ksF4Nv7-uToJsyT2LhzJGFyl-V5_O4q5/view?usp=sharing) @yuri

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped me figure it out:

```
function myFunction() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('12XnwRmBL7ssKBjuku7lJgHKgUqmIijZatFJVamud__M')
   var nameSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
   var nameSheetData = []
   var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("10mZsJX4LQnw5U4sMQ8gXwKVyl3Ua1dlW");
   var folderIndex = pdfFolder.searchFiles("title contains 'pdf'");
   Logger.log(folderIndex)
   nameSheet.appendRow(['Name', 'Bank Book Photo']);
   while ( folderIndex.hasNext() )
   {
       var file = folderIndex.next();
       var url = file.getUrl();
       var name = file.getName();
       nameSheet.appendRow([name, url]);
   }
}
```